# excel vba delete entire row if there is 0 value in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make a VBA code which automatically delete the entire row if the value in column 'D' is 0. im using this code but when I try to run it it gives me an error saying "Application Defined or Object-Defined error". anybody know why ? or is there any other way to do this ?

```
Sub deletezeros()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim searchrange As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set searchrange = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("D2", ActiveSheet.Range("D123432").End(xlUp))

    For i = searchrange.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set c = searchrange.Cells(i)
        If c.Value = "0" Then c.EntireRow.Delete
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps your active sheet is not sheet 2? In any event -- what line triggers the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try something a more simple procedure? Like:

```
    Dim SH As Worksheet
    Set SH = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2")
    Dim LR As Long
    LR = SH.Columns(4).Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
   '-----
    For i = LR To 2 Step -1
        If SH.Cells(i, 4).Value = "0" Then
            SH.Cells(i, 4).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
```

Comment: I tried using yours but it still gives me the same error

Comment: The only explanation is that you don't have any data on `D` column in `sheet2`. Or you don't have any `sheet2` at all...

Comment: In VBA, `0 <> "0"`.

Comment: @user11217663, let's find first `Application Defined or Object-Defined error` :D :D

Comment: oh I know why, I protect the sheet that's why. after I unlock it it works

Comment: how If I want this code to run automatically ? do you know ?

Comment: @JustinJunias If you want help with running this code automatically then you will need to ask as a separate question, although there are a lot of questions on here already asking how to run a macro on cell change. So do a bit of research and testing before asking and if you need help let us know what you have tried.